# Deploy an application's xml file with installer or create it on the fly if it does not exist

Tags: c#, xml, deployment, installation

I am having an xml file like:

```
<CurrentProject>
// Elements like 
// last opened project file to reopen it when app starts
// and more global project independend settings
</CurrentProject>
```

Now I asked myself wether I should deliver this xml file with above empty elements with the installer for my app or should I create this file on the fly on application start if it does not exist else read the values from it.

Consider also that the user could delete this file and that should my application not prevent from working anymore.

What is better and why?

**UPDATE**:

What I did felt ok for me so I post my code here :) It just creates the xml + structure on the fly with some security checks...

```
public ProjectService(IProjectDataProvider provider)
       {
           _provider = provider;   

           string applicationPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
           _projectPath = Path.Combine(applicationPath,@"TBM\Settings.XML");

           if (!File.Exists(_projectPath))
           {
               string dirPath = Path.Combine(applicationPath, @"TBM");

               if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath))
                   Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);

               using (var stream = File.Create(_projectPath))
               {
                   XElement projectElement = new XElement("Project");
                   projectElement.Add(new XElement("DatabasePath"));

                   projectElement.Save(stream, SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);   
               }   
           }                
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

In a similar scenario, I recently went for creating the initial file on the fly.  The main reason I chose this was the fact that I wasn't depending on this file being there and being valid.  As this was a file that's often read from/written to, there's a chance that it could get corrupted (e.g. if the power is lost while the file is being written).

In my code I attempted to open this file for reading and then read the data.  If anywhere during these steps I encountered an error, I simply recreated the file with default values and displayed a corresponding message to the user.

Comment: when u created the xml one the fly did you create the whole structure so later you can just write the values?

Comment: No, I didn't.  Since I kept the DOM of the XML in memory while my application was running, I just created an empty file.  Thinking back, I don't know why I even did that - as all I could do is write a new XML from memory to the file when it was time to save it.

Comment: you kept the dom in the memory, you mean you saved the xml as string in a variable? If yes I think its hard to maintain such a string... if no what else did you mean?

Comment: No, not a string.  The app was written in C++, so I kept a class representing application settings.  Operators `<<` and `>>` were defined for the class to write and read this XML, respectively.  Reading was done using xerces (http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/)

Comment: you did something total different to me see my update. But the talk with you pushed me in the direction where I think its right :) Not a solution but I gave you a point for pushing me ;-)